# AWS - MEAN App - Maintain the uploads folder

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a MEAN app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. Angular is built in /public folder and images are uploaded in /uploads folder. Below is the structure of folders:

[image]

Every time I deploy a new version of the app, the uploads folder is replaced and all the uploaded images are gone. I tried deploying without the uploads folder, and that didn't work either. What's the best solution to maintain the uploads folder?

I'm thinking I'll deploy the app on EC2 manually, without using EBS, and copy the files in S3 manually.

Comment: You should use some kind of external storage instead of keep the images inside the deployable unit. EC2 + S3 could be a solution. But keep in mind that you can deploy in EBS and store the images in S3 (I think that's the best solution because of the simplicity of deploy EBS apps)

Comment: Yes, that does sound like the best solution, thanks! I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Glad to help you! :)